# Por que o FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL não remove alguns caracteres especiais?

Tags: php, input, filter, sanitize

Eu sei como o `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` funciona, mas o que eu não consigo entender é porque ele não remove os seguintes caracteres:

```
! # $% & '* + - =? ^ _ `{|} ~ @. [] .
```

- Eu sei que na documentação está especificando que ele não remove, mas qual o motivo disso?
- Eu nunca vi um e-mail com `Luan{}martins*@hotmail.com`, esse comportamento não é anormal?
- Se ele não consegue verificar o e-mail porque eu deveria usá-lo?

Formulário

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="string">
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="btn"></form>
```

PHP

```
$string = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'string' ,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Gostaria de entender esse motivo, no momento estou escrevendo sobre os tipos de filtro e realmente não encontrei nada que me fizesse entender o motivo de aceitar os caracteres que eu falei, sempre que estou desenvolvendo e quero garantir que seja um e-mail uso o `HTML5`, mas gosto de usar os filtros e normalmente uso parern

Comment: A documentação não cita, mas *provavelmente* é por causa da [RFC 5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322), que [permite esses caracteres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2049502) em um email (por mais estranho que possa parecer).

Comment: Uma ótima observação, além disso no elemento input do html acontece o mesmo, caso coloque type="email" ele válida o email e envia com esses caracteres.

Comment: Eu não tinha reparado que no html ele tambem aceitava os caracteres, mas sempre tive essa duvida de o motivo da aceitação dos caracteres, para validar sempre retirava com o parern, agora que li o documento passado entendi.

Comment: Mas não seria para um caso onde o endereço do e-mail fosse um `IPV6`? Só chutando mesmo. Se bem que esses caracteres aí são bem incomuns

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Na verdade esses caracteres são permitidos no username (antes do `@`). Apesar de incomum e estranho, [é válido](https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/resources/articles/acceptable-email-address-syntax-rfc/) de acordo com a RFC. Provavelmente o PHP segue a mesma regra, mas ainda não achei uma fonte que afirme isso com certeza (pelo que vi, a documentação não diz nem que sim, nem que não)

Comment: Você pode criar um próprio filtro configurando um filter.default dessa forma, poderá ajustar o filtro para maneira que quiser, espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação do PHP para o [FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

> Remove todos os caracteres, exceto letras, dígitos e !#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~@.[].

E de acordo com o RFC para a sintaxe de um e-mail, na parte local (antes do @) pode ter até 64 caracteres e consistir de qualquer combinação de letras, dígitos ou qualquer um desses caracteres especiais.
Uma observação: o símbolo de ponto final "." tem algumas restrições, ele não pode ser o primeiro nem o último digito do e-mail e também não pode ser consecutivo, ou seja, vários pontos seguidos.

Fonte: [mailboxvalidator.com](https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/resources/articles/acceptable-email-address-syntax-rfc/)